# django pagination <if current page> in template

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I am quite new to django, and I have just about managed to create a ListView using CBV's and I am trying to display this on my template. For this, I have worked out the following using django docs:

```
{% if is_paginated %}

<div class="row">
<div class="span8 offset3">
<div class="pagination pagination-centered">


    <ul>

        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'myurl' %}?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Prev</a></li>
        {% endif %}

        {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
           {% if page_obj.has_next %}
               <li><a href="{% url 'myurl' %}?page={{i}}">{{i}}</a></li>
           {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'myurl' %}?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a></li>
        {% endif %}

    </ul>


</div>
</div>
</div>

{% endif %}
```

Now, the problem is, I am using twitter bootstrap, and they recommend the following style to "deactivate" current page while paginating the objects:

```
<ul class="pagination">
 <li class="disabled"><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
 <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
</ul>
```

So, on the current page, I would like to include `<li class="active">` to disable the button- but I am unable to figure out a way to do this using my above pagination on my template. Basically, I would somehow need to find out if the current page is equal to the current page number and then apply the `li class` to this.

Would appreciate on clues on how to solve this issue.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't understand, can't you just use `{% if page_obj.has_previous %}class="active"{% else %}class="disabled"{% endif %}`?

Comment: @rednaw: I tried what you said before posting the question - for some reason, all page numbers seem to be "active" and none disabled. I am either being really foolish or something is weird!

Comment: for the page numbers you should probably use something like `{% if page.obj.current_page_number == i %}class="active"{% else %}class="disabled"{% endif %}'`

Comment: can you show up the views or the files you are using , may be it can be helpful.

Comment: @rednaw: `page.obj.current_page_number` - is this valid? i.e is it documented? I cant see this anywhere. Anyway, I tried using it and it does not seem to work.

Comment: So, when I do for example: `{% ifequal i 1 %}<li class="active">
{% else %}<li><a href="{% url 'myurl' %}?page={{i}}">{{i}}</a></li>{% endifequal %}` then everything works fine for the first page. So, the logic is correct. But my question is how do I show the current page number on my template. So, I need to do `{% ifequal i tag_spits_current_page_number %}....` I guess my question is what is the `tag_spits_current_page_number` here.

Comment: OK - solved it finally. Answered.

Answer (score 3):

So, I tried:
`page_obj.number`
..and bang..current page number...